# Replacing floor boards and joists

Tags: floor

I am replacing water damaged floor boards in my bathroom. They were previously tiled and I will be tiling them again. It's an apartment and below the floor is concrete, with joists between the concrete and the boards.

The joists are 45x90mm which I am struggling to find. Is this not a normal size?

Also the joists have a black foam tape on the bottom about 10mm thick which I am also struggling to find.

The joists are not attached to anything and are resting on the floor, held together by the nailed floor boards, which I thought was unusual

The apartment is purpose build and around 10 years old

Comment: 45 x 90 is about 1 3/4 x 3 1/2" - about the real size of a 2 x 4.

Comment: It does seem kind of strange. Are the joists water damaged? Is this "structural" or "cosmetic" water damage? Can you post some pictures?

Comment: I eventually found 'Scapa 3259' which comes in many sizes and was fine for the job

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been abandoned

Comment: @FreeMan I'm not sure why it matters considering it's over a year old, but regardless you can see that I responded to the below answer in the comments

Comment: Because there is no accepted answer, it will continue to be bumped to the top of the queue every few months in the hopes of getting an answer that can be accepted. If the one that's been provided has proven useful to you, give it a check mark. Otherwise, it probably doesn't matter to you any more, so it won't matter if it's closed or not.

Comment: Voting to close. The only real question seems to be about acquisition of a particular size of wood. That's what saws are for.

Comment: Either that or revise to ask something more clear and specific. We're happy to help, but as you can see from the lack of response the question could use improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the "joists" are water damaged too or you wouldn't be looking for new ones. The size you mentioned is close to a 2x4. The foam tape it probably heavy weather stripping used as a cushion to your floating floor. If you can't find the exact size you might want to just replace the whole floor since you'll be tiling it over or use 2x4's and shim the difference.

Comment: Since they are giving metric dimensions the may not have inch lumber available (this site is world wide). I would probably sister something close to span the damaged area.

Comment: I keep forgetting that... I'm in Florida, U.S.A.

Comment: Yes, only metric is readily available for me, and in the end I found 1mm shorter joists so fitted 1mm thicker foam tape